# Page preferences dialog in WPF

Tags: wpf, printing, printdialog, page-setup

I'm fiddling with adding the ability to output from a program I'm working on to both PDF and XPS. Initially both were just done via printers (pdf printer/xps writer) but I'd like to do it a little more directly.

The issue I've run into is that there doesn't seem to be a page preferences dialog for WPF. Is there one and I just can't find it, or does something like this have to be custom built in WPF?

I can display the print dialog and then just not actually call PrintDialog.Print, but that's not really any better than just having the user print using a PDF printer. I can retrieve all the page settings from the print dialog, but the user would actually be setting those settings for whichever printer was currently selected.

I just need a dialog with all the standard printer preference options, like page size, margins, copies, etc. Not difficult to create, but I'm surprised I can't find one...

Answer (score 2):

My answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727328/how-can-i-invoke-the-dialog-to-set-printer-options-manually/1416679#1416679)** should help you. What are the chances... I **just** answered it, and I stumble across your question :)

Hope this helps you!!