# Which Windows API opens the print properties dialog?

Tags: windows, api, dialog, printing

I would like to hook into an Office application just before the print properties dialog is opened (the dialog where you choose the paper, printer, etc.).
Which Windows API opens this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links which document this
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167345
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183576%28VS.85%29.aspx

and this SO question:
[How to show printer properties/preferences dialog and save changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437337/how-to-show-printer-properties-preferences-dialog-and-save-changes)